# How to add a pagination for foreach loop data in PHP

Tags: php, foreach, pagination

I have set of data displaying inside my foreach loop, i want to show only 10 at a time and display a paging for others. pls advice

```
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            ?>
              <div class="name">
                    <img src="<?php echo $file->getIconPath() ?>" alt="" />
                    <div class="info">
                        <h2 class="filename"><?php echo $file->filename ?></h2>
                        <div class="path">
                            <?php echo $file->filetype ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
 <?php }?>
```

Comment: You could retrieve 10 of the files from wherever you get them. Then you wont have to alter the loop and you can then separate the display loop from retrieving loop

Answer (score 4):

`array_slice` is the function you need to split an array. This is how a pagination works in arrays.

```
$allFiles = globe("*");
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0;
$count = count($allFiles);
$perPage = 5;
$numberOfPages = ceil($count / $perPage);
$offset = $page * $perPage;
$files = array_slice($allFiles, $offset, $perPage);
foreach($files as $file){
   //
}
```

Comment: showing syntax error on this:$page = isset($_GET['page']) : $_GET['page'] ? 0;
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'  this is a error please tell why it shows.